# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined when calling a dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call the `DeletePost` function from

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    DeletePost: () => dispatch(DeletePost())
});
```

However, react is showing

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

**PostList.js**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
const removePost = (id) => {
  // showing error below this line cannot read props
  this.props.DeletePost(id);
}

const PostList = ({props, posts}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post, i) => (
                <Paper key={i} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                        {post.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                        {post.post_content}
                        <h5>
                            by: {post.username}</h5>
                        <h5>
                            {moment(post.createdAt).calendar()}</h5>
                    </Typography>
                    <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(post.id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                </Paper>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    DeletePost: () => dispatch(DeletePost())
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

Comment: Can you put your removePost inside the component?

Comment: you mean the `DeletePost` inside the button onClick handler ?

Comment: no the const removePost, place that inside the component.

Comment: even after putting the removePost inside the PostList component, it still returns `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` in the `removePost` function is not bound to a context. You need to place it inside the `PostList` function. Also, there are three errors in your code.

1. Component props

The Component function takes `props` as parameter. Either use the props object (`props.DeletePost`), or destruct the `DeletePost` function (`{ DeletePost }`) from the props object. In your case you are somehow trying to do both. Destructing props from props (equal to `props.props`).

Use props object

```
const PostList = (props) => {
  // use props.DeletePost() and props.posts.
}
```

Destruct props object

```
const PostList = (props) => {
  // use DeletePost() and posts.
}
```

2. mapDispatchToProps

You are not passing the post id through to the dispatched `DeletePost` function.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
  DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
```

3. Calling removePost on every rerender.

The onClick event prop takes a function which be called upon a user click. But what you are doing is that instead of passing the onClick prop a function, you are calling the `removePost` function instead. The remove function will in its turn return undefined, yielding no action upon button click. However, as your are calling the removePost function upon render, the DeletePost action will be dispatch. As I assume the action will update the state, which will cause the component to rerender. And you are stuck in an inifite loop, as removePost will be called again.

To solve this. The removePost function should return a new function instead. The returned function from removePost will now be assigned to the onClick prop, and called upon button click.

Example

```
  const removePost = (id) => () => {
    DeletePost(id);
  }


const PostList = ({DeletePost, posts}) => {
  // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each time the Component rerenders.
  const removePost = (id) => () => {
    DeletePost(id);
  }

  return ( ... )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
  DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
```

Comment: thanks this seems to be working, however im getting a loop.

Comment: `5:8000/api/posts/delete/undefined:1 DELETE http://localhost:8000/api/posts/delete/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: its supposed to show a 404 error if i click the button, not when it renders

Comment: Because you are not passing the id in the DeletePost function in mapStateToProps. See code in answer.

Comment: it works now thanks so much, appreciate your assistance.

Comment: possible to explain the significance for doing `=> ()`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const PostList = ({props, posts}) => {
    const removePost = (id) => {
    // showing error below this line cannot read props
    this.props.DeletePost(id);
   }
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post, i) => (
                <Paper key={i} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                        {post.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography component="p">
                        {post.post_content}
                        <h5>
                            by: {post.username}</h5>
                        <h5>
                            {moment(post.createdAt).calendar()}</h5>
                    </Typography>
                    <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(post.id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                </Paper>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

Comment: i still get the error `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`.  above `this.props.DeletePost(id);`

Comment: Also, add id as a parameter in the mapDispatchToProps

Comment: Honestly this would probably work better if you turned it into a Class based component.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what the issue is and how/why your solution fixes it.

Comment: Sorry Yeah, I was kinda explaining it in the comments and just figured to post.  I'll be more specific next time

Comment: thank you for your assistance, but i got it working with another solution.